# How to list the path of each node.js modules loaded in memory

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs

I'm developing a mean.js app using node v4.0.0 but I run into troubles due to wrong dependencies in one of the loaded modules.

After successful npm install there are 2 different versions of passport module saved in the node_modules folder due to different dependencies requirements:

**v0.1.18** in folders

`node_modules/passport-paypal-openidconnect/node_modules/passport-openidconnect`
`node_modules/passport-cas`

and **v0.3.0** in folder

`node_modules/passport`

The app runs, but it was buggy and after some debugging I found out that the old version was loaded in memory instead of the newest required by the passport module.

If I'm not wrong node loads only one version of each module, and so my question:

How can I retrieve a full list with **path** and **version** of loaded modules when the app runs?

Answer (score 0):

```
require('module')._cache
```

is the object having all loaded modules.
to view the names ->

```
Object.keys(require('module')._cache);
```

Comment: it does not include the user defined modules？